# How to move back custom button in navigationController on swift 5

Tags: ios, swift, navigation, uinavigationcontroller

I have a problem working on the UI. I was using a `navigationController` to move the screen.

But I didn't want to use the basic back button, so I hid the basic back button, added the navigation bar to the storyboard,

and added items to make the back button. However, the screen does not move to the previous screen. How can I get to the previous screen?

**Basic backButton** // I'm hiding it now.

[image: back]

**I want to use the back button I made.**

[image]

**Backward command for back button items.**

```swift
    override func viewWillDisappear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillDisappear(animated)

        self.navigationController?.setNavigationBarHidden(true, animated: animated)
    }

    @IBAction func backButton(_ sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil) // Did not worked!
    }
```

In addition, I would like to remove the underline of the navigation header. How can I remove it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this in a project for the same situation:

```
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

this can be used after iOS 13 deprecation of keyWindow:

```
let keyW = UIApplication.shared.windows.filter {$0.isKeyWindow}.first
keyW?.rootViewController?.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
```

This can also be used:

```
self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: false)
```

or

```
self.navigationController?.popToRootViewController(animated: false)
```

About the button:

Why not just use the navigation button by creating this hierarchy in storyboard:

[image]

Then just change the image for btn to your custom image (I use burger1.png) like this:

[image]

Comment: get warning 'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes'keyWindow' was deprecated in iOS 13.0: Should not be used for applications that support multiple scenes as it returns a key window across all connected scenes

Comment: There is a problem trying to move the back button. The back button is hidden in the status bar and cannot be clicked. How do I adjust the back button's Margin value to the height of the status bar?

Comment: That's what we're already using. However, the back button is at the height of the status bar, which makes it difficult to press the button. I think we can adjust the Margin value of the navigation bar, but I don't know how.

Comment: Then something else is probably disturbing the button, can you show a screenshot of your storyboard and storyboard hierarchy?

Comment: My screen is FullScreen, not SafeArea. If that's what this is about, then I have to adjust the margin value of the header.

Comment: It’s hard to help without seeing a screenshot of the storyboard and the storyboard hierarchy

Comment: Which part of the storyboard screenshot do you need?

Comment: Maybe you should create a new question for that specific problem, screenshot of the entire view with the button and the hierarchy for that view on the left in storyboard

Answer (score 1):

You can customize back button with following code

```
    let buttonView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))


let buttonImageView = UIImageView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 25, height: 25))
        buttonImageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        buttonImageView.image = UIImage(named: "back_button")

        let btnLogo = UIButton(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 50, height: 50))
        btnLogo.setTitle("", for: .normal)
        btnLogo.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        btnLogo.layer.masksToBounds = true
        btnLogo.addTarget(self, action: #selector(backButton), for: .touchUpInside)
        buttonView.addSubview(buttonImageView)
        buttonView.addSubview(btnLogo)

        let barButton = UIBarButtonItem(customView: buttonView)
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = barButton
```

if you are using navigationbar you should use navigationController.popViewController instead of dismiss method

Comment: There is a problem trying to move the back button. The back button is hidden in the status bar and cannot be clicked. How do I adjust the back button's Margin value to the height of the status bar?